# Apache Symbolic Link SymLinks returns HTTP 500 error

Tags: apache

The only thing in http://localhost/.htaccess is this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Alias /1 /2
```

...and I get an HTTP 500 error. Tried it with one, both, either or directories existing (e.g. localhost/1/). Not seeing anything for tutorials. Can I get this to work without modifying the server's httpd.conf configuration file?

**Goal**: use a single (same) directory for two or more sites that are structured the same with different content.

**Condition**: This MUST be mirrored on a live server which means I do NOT have access to the server configuration.

If SymLinks can NOT be used in any way via .htaccess without modifying the server configuration then this approach is not one I can take.

Comment: Maybe a little obvious, but... does it work *without* the file?

Comment: A 500 will log something in your Apache error log.  What does it say?

Comment: @Trott, I should have thought about the error log; "Alias not allowed here".

Comment: @minitech I don't want to modify the server configuration, this is an alternative approach to using a mod rewrite. I can look up various settings in the configuration however.

Comment: @John: No, I mean, are you sure it's actually the fault of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), you cannot use `Alias` in a `.htaccess` file.

For the `Alias` directive, it lists the `Context` as `server config, virtual host`.  If you were able to use it in a `.htaccess` file then `.htaccess` would appear in the `Context` for the directive in the documentation.

Some options to solve the problem:

- Make `/1` a symlink to the `/2` directory.  (Is `/1` already symlink to `/2`?  If so, just get rid of the `Alias` statement.  You don't need it in that case.)
- Move the `Alias` directive to the server config.
- Use `mod_rewrite` rules in your `.htaccess` file.  This will only work if your `/2` directory is under docroot.
- Use a `Redirect` directive. This also requires tht your `/2` directory is under your docroot. It's different from `Alias`, but it might be close enough for you depending on what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If I can't touch the server configuration and you see localhost then that should imply that I will mirror this effort on a live server where I do NOT have access to the configuration file. Also this is NOT a redirect in any sense, SymLinks are supposed to allow access via a virtual path which is not a redirect.